# Find the maximum cost path from the bottom-left corner to the top-right corner

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

**Hi, everybody! I try to find best solution with assignment in title. But I don't understand how I can output way of calculation. I write python program, it can output random massive and max sum, but I need way too.**

```
from collections import deque as queue
import random
import numpy as np
array=[]
def creatArray():
    r = 0
    x = 5
    y = 5
    global array
    for i in range(x):
        array.append([])
        for j in range(y):
            array[i].append(random.randint(0,100))
            r += 1
    return array
creatArray()

ROW = 5
COL = 5


# Check whether given cell (row, col)
# is a valid cell or not.
def isValid(p):
    # Return true if row number and column number
    # is in range
    return (p[0] >= 0) and (p[1] < COL)


# Function to find maximum cost to reach
# top right corner from bottom left corner
def find_max_cost(mat):
    max_val = [[0 for i in range(COL)] for i in range(ROW)]

    max_val[ROW - 1][0] = mat[ROW - 1][0]

    # Starting po
    src = [ROW - 1, 0]
    # Create a queue for traversal
    q = queue()
    q.appendleft(src)  # Enqueue source cell

    # Do a BFS starting from source cell
    # on the allowed direction
    while (len(q) > 0):
        curr = q.pop()

        # Find up point
        up = [curr[0] - 1, curr[1]]

        # if adjacent cell is valid, enqueue it.
        if (isValid(up)):
            max_val[up[0]][up[1]] = max(max_val[up[0]][up[1]], mat[up[0]][up[1]] + max_val[curr[0]][curr[1]])
            q.appendleft(up)

        # Find right po
        right = [curr[0], curr[1] + 1]
        if (isValid(right)):
            max_val[right[0]][right[1]] = max(max_val[right[0]][right[1]],
                                              mat[right[0]][right[1]] + max_val[curr[0]][curr[1]])
            q.appendleft(right)
        # Find dig po
        dig = [curr[0]-1, curr[1] + 1]
        if (isValid(dig)):
            max_val[dig[0]][dig[1]] = max(max_val[dig[0]][dig[1]],
                                              mat[dig[0]][dig[1]] + max_val[curr[0]][curr[1]])
            q.appendleft(dig)
    # Return the required answer
    return max_val[0][COL - 1]


#Driver code
print("Given matrix is ")

for i in range(ROW):
    for j in range(COL):
        print(array[i][j], end=" ")
    print()

print("Maximum cost is ", find_max_cost(array))
```

I have not any ideas.
Output my current code:
Given matrix is
97 16 73 23 43
99 30 37 71 29
5 52 89 98 19
73 66 89 97 15
96 2 15 31 96
Maximum cost is  662

Out, which I need:
Given matrix is
97 16 73 23 43
99 30 37 71 29
5 52 89 98 19
73 66 89 97 15
96 2 15 31 96
Maximum cost is  662
Way is 96-73-5-99-97-16-73-23-46

Comment: you only need to keep the history when you update the max to know from which point you came to the current position then you can track back and find you whole path. I will edit your code to work so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive solution would just be to store the route taken to achieve the max in every cell in `max_value` as you build the `max_value` array.  A very ugly solution would look something like below

NOTE: the implementation below does not count for multiple valid 'way's, it will simply choose the first valid 'way' it finds.  More logic would be needed to get all valid 'way's or to get a specific valid 'way' based on some criteria

```
from collections import deque as queue
import random
import numpy as np
array=[]
def creatArray():
    r = 0
    x = 5
    y = 5
    global array
    for i in range(x):
        array.append([])
        for j in range(y):
            array[i].append(random.randint(0,100))
            r += 1
    return array

creatArray()
# array = [
# [97,16,73,23,43],
# [99,30,37,71,29],
# [5,52,89,98,19],
# [73,66,89,97,15],
# [96,2,15,31,96]
# ]

ROW = 5
COL = 5


# Check whether given cell (row, col)
# is a valid cell or not.
def isValid(p):
    # Return true if row number and column number
    # is in range
    return (p[0] >= 0) and (p[1] < COL)


# Function to find maximum cost to reach
# top right corner from bottom left corner
def find_max_cost(mat):
    max_val = [[[0, []] for i in range(COL)] for i in range(ROW)]

    max_val[ROW - 1][0] = [mat[ROW - 1][0], []]

    # Starting po
    src = [ROW - 1, 0]
    # Create a queue for traversal
    q = queue()
    q.appendleft(src)  # Enqueue source cell

    # Do a BFS starting from source cell
    # on the allowed direction
    while (len(q) > 0):
        curr = q.pop()

        # Find up point
        up = [curr[0] - 1, curr[1]]

        # if adjacent cell is valid, enqueue it.
        if (isValid(up)):
            enqueue(mat, max_val, q, up, curr)

        # Find right po
        right = [curr[0], curr[1] + 1]
        if (isValid(right)):
            enqueue(mat, max_val, q, right, curr)

        # Find dig po
        dig = [curr[0]-1, curr[1] + 1]
        if (isValid(dig)):
            enqueue(mat, max_val, q, dig, curr)

    # Return the required answer
    max_val[0][COL - 1][1].append((0, COL-1))
    return max_val[0][COL - 1]

def enqueue(mat, max_val, q, new, curr):
    mvc = max_val[new[0]][new[1]][0]
    mvn = mat[new[0]][new[1]] + max_val[curr[0]][curr[1]][0]
    if mvn > mvc:
        max_val[new[0]][new[1]][0] = mvn
        l = list(max_val[curr[0]][curr[1]][1])
        l.append((curr[0],curr[1]))
        max_val[new[0]][new[1]][1] = l
    q.appendleft(new)


#Driver code
max_cost = find_max_cost(array)
print "Maximum cost is " + str(max_cost[0])
s = ''
for t in max_cost[1]:
    s = s + str(array[t[0]][t[1]]) + ' '
print "Way is " + s
```

Answer (score 0):

just keep the history of when was the previous points, means you only need to have a space same size of the original matrix when you update the max value, you also update which was previous point: (your code slightly edited, the only line added is this, rest is a bit reorganizing).

```
p_dict[tuple(point)] = tuple(curr)
```

in your find max_cost function.

```
p_dict = dict()
# Function to find maximum cost to reach
# top right corner from bottom left corner
def find_max_cost(mat):
    max_val = [[0 for i in range(COL)] for i in range(ROW)]

    max_val[ROW - 1][0] = mat[ROW - 1][0]

    # Starting po
    src = (ROW - 1, 0)
    # Create a queue for traversal
    q = queue()
    q.appendleft(src)  # Enqueue source cell

    # Do a BFS starting from source cell
    # on the allowed direction
   
    while (len(q) > 0):
        curr = q.pop()    
        # Find all point
        points = [[curr[0] - 1, curr[1]],[curr[0], curr[1] + 1],[curr[0]-1, curr[1] + 1]]
        for point in points:
            # if adjacent cell is valid, enqueue it.
            if (isValid(point)):
                if mat[point[0]][point[1]] + max_val[curr[0]][curr[1]] > max_val[point[0]][point[1]]:
                    max_val[point[0]][point[1]] = mat[point[0]][point[1]] + max_val[curr[0]][curr[1]]
                    p_dict[tuple(point)] = tuple(curr)
                q.appendleft(point)
    # Return the required answer
    return max_val[0][COL - 1]
```

and finally, track your path:

```
cur = (0, COL -1)
path = [cur]
while not cur == (ROW -1, 0):
    cur = p_dict[cur]
    path.append(cur)
```